# PHP PDO & SQL Search wildcard bind parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a search function for a site and have created the sql code, which was generated from PHPMYADMIN, see below;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bg85ow`.`sessions` WHERE CONVERT(`SessionName` USING utf8) LIKE '%:SessionName1%'";
```

Here is the PHP code processing the query;

```
//bind params
                $SessionName1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search');
                $stmt -> bindValue(':SessionName1', $SessionName1, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                //execute
                $success = $stmt -> execute();

                if (!$success){
                     print $stmt->errorInfo()[2]; //PDO driver error message
                }

                else{
                }

                //array
                $r = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $dbh = null;

                if(!$r)
                {
                    echo "No Results";
                }      

                foreach ((array) $r as $row) {
                 echo $row['SessionId'];
                 echo $row['SessionName'];
                }
```

For some reason this will not return any results the `execute` part is working fine and passing the success test but then once it gets to the array it returns no results.

I checked and `$SessionName1` has the term in it from search so it is being passed to the query ok.

When I change the `%:SessionName1%` to `football` which is the search term I am testing with, the code returns the results fine but once changed back to `:SessionName1` it will not return the results even though the search term is exactly the same.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong, I spent ages looking at this and cannot see the error.

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this but I couldn't find one specific to this issue, also I am a beginner with PHP and SQL.

Comment: May be you have mistype in `$stmt -> bindValue(':SessionName1', $SessionName1, PDO::PARAM_STR);` ... there is you have bind `SessionName1` place instead of `SessionName` in the string ... i.e. this must to be like this : `$stmt -> bindValue(':SessionName', $SessionName1, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: you have to use correct sessionName.

Comment: [A placeholder have to represent a complete data literal only - a string or a number namely.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like)

Comment: The spelling mistake is just and error when I copied it, I cut some off and typed it back manually, in the code it is actually `%:SessionName1%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this Example :** Check where is you are wrong.

```
// Get the keyword from query string
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
// Prepare the command
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` LIKE :keyword');
// Put the percentage sing on the keyword
$keyword = "%".$keyword."%";
// Bind the parameter
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Ok so I tried this and received this message `Notice: Undefined index: SessionName in D:\xampp\htdocs\PPW4\SearchSessions.php on line 9` It does return everything from the table but not the search query

Comment: Ok fixed it made an error in a variable name, this worked thanks for the help

Comment: I mention it already in comments of question, :--> you have to use correct sessionName. Anyway you did it. :)